# Validate one attribute of an object using json schema

Tags: angularjs, validation, attributes, jsonschema, client-side-validation

I'm currenty using tv4 (json-schema validator) to validate (client-side) an object with a json-schema, which worked pretty well.

But when I'm changing one value of an attribute, I want that this value is the only one, which should be validated.

For example I have a user:

```
var user = { Name: 'Username', Age: 20 };
```

And the schema:

```
{
    "title": "UserValidation",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Name": {
            "minLength": 4
        },
        "Age": {
            "type": "int"
        }
    }
}
```

And when I only change the name, I don't want to check, if the attribute "Age" is valid.

Reason: When I have a big object (with sub-models etc.) it will validate all properties. And I don't know if it's gonna be a performance problem (some day...).

- Is this a possible case with schema-validation?
- Or are there better
  ways to validate objects?

I'm using AngularJS btw.

Best regards and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a performance problem until you have a performance problem. :)

There's no technical reason a partial-update validator like that shouldn't exist (I know of at least one, but it's not exactly speedy in the first place).  There are also faster "from-scratch" validators ([some with benchmarks](https://rawgit.com/zaggino/z-schema/master/benchmark/results.html)), including some with very similar APIs/error-reports, so if in the future you do start seeing performance problems then you could switch then without much fuss.

However, given that this is happening client-side (so you don't have scaling problems with more users), I wouldn't worry about it yet.

Comment: It's usefull if you use PATCH or sub PUT like `PUT product/1` vs `PUT product/1/offers`

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to pick out the sub-schema to validate the sub-property.  That should be easy to do, validating user.Name with schema.properties.Name.

A problem with just validating a sub-property is that some parts of the validation isn't on the property itself.  For example, there could be a required-array on the object above.

Comment: While this might work for some schemas, in general this isn't possible.  Clauses like `oneOf` or `dependencies` mean that changes in one part of the data could affect a completely different area (including removal/addition of schemas).